# Using C# file from an ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I may have a small problem defining what I ask but I'll do my best:
I built an ASP.NET website and I want to use Microsoft Azure. So I defined in a C# class file an object that extends TableServiceEntity.
I'm trying to get the code behind page of a certain webpage to know this type of class. But I can't seem to find the right way to do it. I guess it has to do with some Using.

It is in the same project as the webpage in a different folder.
Thanks,

Comment: Post the relevant code in the code behind and in the class you defined.

Comment: Thanks James, I found the problem. It has to do with Namsespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue adding Namespace to my C# class.
The first solution I found was to move it too AppCode but that is the same as giving it a namespace.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, don't forget to mark the thread as answered.